# What is the use of unique=true for bidirectional one-to-many with join table

Tags: java, hibernate

As per the [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch08.html#assoc-bidirectional-join-12m),

`section: 8.5.1. one-to-many / many-to-one`:

The mapping file is:

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id" column="personId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <set name="addresses" 
        table="PersonAddress">
        <key column="personId"/>
        <many-to-many column="addressId"
            unique="true"
            class="Address"/>
    </set>
</class>

<class name="Address">
    <id name="id" column="addressId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <join table="PersonAddress" 
        inverse="true" 
        optional="true">
        <key column="addressId"/>
        <many-to-one name="person"
            column="personId"
            not-null="true"/>
    </join>
</class>
```

Here for many-to-many there is `unique="true"` but still hibernate has not created any unique constraint at DB level.

DDL's generated by Hibernate are:

```
Hibernate: create table ADDRESS (addressId number(10,0) not null, primary key (addressId))
Hibernate: create table PERSON (personId number(10,0) not null, primary key (personId))
Hibernate: create table PersonAddress (addressId number(10,0) not null, personId number(10,0) not null, primary key (personId, addressId))
Hibernate: alter table PersonAddress add constraint FK_g7rqpos3mwhjs6ipfxn6myn3w foreign key (addressId) references ADDRESS
Hibernate: alter table PersonAddress add constraint FK_m5y6eriigdoy1olr7k28a9h6u foreign key (personId) references PERSON
```

So if Hibernate is not creating any unique constraint then why we need to mention it in mapping file? Can someone please explain, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the **unique** attribute of the key element instead:

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id" column="personId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <set name="addresses" 
        table="PersonAddress">
        <key column="personId" unique="true"/>
        <many-to-many column="addressId"                
            class="Address"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad, but as per my understanding the relationship between Person and Address is Many-to-one so adding unique for addressId is correct as mentioned in my question. I am just following what is there in document but I don't see any unique constraint when hibernate generated the DDL commands.

Comment: You can add the unique constraint on addressId instead of personId. If the question is what is that unique on many-to-many then I can't find out from Hibernate code as well.